# Find out files which have been downloaded

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to retrieve a file from the server so the client can download it. Is there any way I can find out which files have been downloaded? Maybe if a text file could be stored somewhere which could keep on adding filenames as they are downloaded are accessed?

```
function downloadPdf(){    

//fetch the registrationId from the input#url
let registrationId = document.getElementById("url").value;        

//transform the registrationId string to lower case
registrationId = registrationId.trim().toLowerCase();

const pdfUrl = `/ooecertificate/${registrationId}.pdf`;        

//this is the statement to redirect the browser to the wanted url
//now commented because it wouldn't work here on the snippet

//window.location.href = pdfUrl;

//on its behalf I'm writing the url on console
console.log(pdfUrl); }
```

```html
label.fieldLabel{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

label.fieldDescription{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;   
  border: solid 1px gray;
  padding: 1em;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="fieldDescription">
  Your registration id is your firstname+registered email id:<br>
  For example..<br>
  if your name is SAMMY DIXIT and your registered email id is SAMMY.DIXIT@GMAIL.COM<br>
  your REGISTRATION ID WILL BE: <b>sammysammy.dixit@gmail.com</b>
  </label> 

  <label class="fieldLabel">ENTER YOUR REGISTRATION ID:</label>   

  <input type="text" name="url" id="url"> 

  <button onclick="downloadPdf();">Download</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Why is your code in two different snippets and a bare code block? It should be all in one.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to store the download count information:

1. In a DATABASE

   This would be the best way since you would have access to the database from anywhere.

   The downside is that you have to implement a connection between a cloud-hosted database or a server-hosted database. Both ways you would have to pay for the service (although there are some free and limited alternatives).
2. In a FILE

   You could store the information in a local .txt file and update it everytime a user clicks the download button but this would work only in the same computer and it's not recommended to do so

Hope this helps you

Comment: There's also localstorage within the browser - better than trying to write to the filesystem

Comment: how to implement it?

Comment: @ADyson, how would localstorage work here? It could keep track on a per-browser basis, but would still need to relay back to the server to actually track it overall.

Comment: @rajiv could you please specify which technology are you using for developing? Is it just plain html/css/js or you're using a framework?

Comment: @user1599011 well it's hardly any worse than your second (local filesystem) based approach - that would be limited to local machine only, albeit it would be cross-browser. Just offering it as a more secure and easier option if server-side tracking is not an option for the OP.

Comment: @Dev-it-a-dev  plain html/css/js integrated as snippet in webpage

Comment: @rajiv To implement something like this you would need to follow a guide or tutorials on internet. I could recommend you searching for javascript+(Cloud-hosting database providers) on google. For example javascript + firebase tutorial and so on...